# C++ templated template deduction sidestep possible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I have a compile time situation that can be resolved with the use of macros but I wonder if there's a better route.  Here's a very simplified version of the concept for illustration purposes (the real thing has quite a few more "Do" states and uses a switch in the macro) :

```
int DoA(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int DoB(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}

template <typename F> int DoFunc1(int a, int b, F func)
{
    return func(a,b);
}

template <typename F> int DoFunc2 (int a, int b, F func)
{
    a *= 2;
    b++;
    return func(a,b);
}

#define ChooseFunc(type, a, b, func)  (((type)) ? (func)((a), (b), (DoA)) : (func)((a), (b), (DoB)))

int CallerA(bool state, int a, int b) 
{
    return ChooseFunc(state, a, b, DoFunc1);
}

int CallerB(bool state, int a, int b) 
{
    return ChooseFunc(state, a, b, DoFunc2);
}
```

Now what I'd love to be able to do is dispense with the macro and use something like this instead :

```
int ChooseFunc(bool type, int a, int b, auto func)
{
    if (type)
        return func(a, b, DoA);

    return func(a, b, DoB);
}
```

But obviously this wont compile as the compiler can't deduce the template types.

The question is, is there a cunning nicer way of doing this?

Comment: Depending on the particulars, implementing `ChooseFunc` in terms of `if constexpr(...)` might work, as is. `type` must be a template parameter.

Comment: I did not know about if constexpr, thanks!  However I'm not sure how that would apply here.  In this instance the issue is more one of how to pass an argument-less template function 'DoFunc1' or 'DoFunc2' to a second function that then applies the arguments.  Maybe you have an example?

Comment: Don't edit answers into your question. Instead accept the answer that best answers it.

Comment: Noted.  But in my defense the answers are only partial, someone reading the thread may not know how to change the surrounding signatures to make use of the suggestions.  I felt it would be more useful to others to see the correct answers in full (and working) and know the assembler assessment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a functor class

```
struct Func1 {
    template<typename F>
    int operator()(int a, int b, F func) { return DoFunc1(a, b, func); }
};

// Likewise for DoFunc2
```

And pass a functor instead.

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar.

I'll update the OP to contain the solution code for others.

Answer (score 0):

Write your functions as function objects:

```
constexpr auto DoFunc1 = [](int a, int b, auto func)->int
{
    return func(a,b);
};

constexpr auto DoFunc2 = [](int a, int b, auto func)->int
{
    a *= 2;
    b++;
    return func(a,b);
};
```

With this approach you can keep your `ChooseFunc()` function template.

Comment: Another great solution!  I'll add it to the original post for others